# Getting the "return value of a function" node js to use as a varaiable outside the function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to get the uid value returned successfully by the following function, and use it as a variable outside of the function as a constant or variable. Below is my code. I am new to node js. please help me. thank you in advance

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
    var userdata = userRecord.toJSON();
    var uid = userdata.uid;
    console.log('uid', uid);
    return uid;
});
```

Comment: You are on the right track with Promises. If you really need to get the value back to the lower level, you can use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Your code creates a promise.  You use either `.then()` or `await` with that promise to get its resolved value.  `return uid` sets the resolved value of the promise.  So you use `.then()` or `await` with that promise to get access to that value.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

**No**, you can not use **uid** value outside your **function(userRecord)** function. This is due to **Asynchronously** nature of javascript.

There are dirty techniques to make it works, but are **dirty**

Here some lectures:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/callbacks-javascript/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38898933/3957754 (good for understand)
- https://dev.to/joelnet/why-async-code-is-so-damn-confusing-and-a-how-to-make-it-easy-3441

## Synchronous way (other languages like java, c#, etc)

```js
//this sentence wait until userRecord
var userRecord = getUserByEmail(email);
//userRecord is ready to use as variable in 
//any section of your code
var uid = getUidFromUser(userRecord);
createUserUidInDatabase(uid);
```

## Asynchronous way with callbacks (javascript)

```js
function createUserUidInDatabase(uid){
  //...
}

function getUidFromUser(userRecord){
  var userdata = userRecord.toJSON();
  var uid = userdata.uid;
  return createUserUidInDatabase(uid);
}

function getUserByEmail(email, callback){
  admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
    .then(function(userRecord) {      
      return callback(userRecord);
  });
}

getUserByEmail("marty@stackoverflow.com",getUidFromUser);
```

## Asynchronous way with promises (javascript)

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/347/javascript-promises-mastering-the-asynchronous/your-first-code-with-promises